# Multiple update only works on one of the query in jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sql-update, prepared-statement

I have a section in my application which require to update two tables at the same time (WORKTR and BRTR).

However, the program only works on the first table update query while the second query did not work, resulting only a table been updated. There are no error prompt at the Log error.

Here is my jdbc code to update both table:

```
                String query=("UPDATE WORKTR SET status = ? WHERE Pf_no = ? AND status = ? AND Scan_by= ? AND Start_date= ?");
                            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                            // set the preparedstatement parameters
                            ps.setString(1,a_status);
                            ps.setString(2,OperatorPF);
                            ps.setString(3,b_status);
                            ps.setString(4,PIC);
                            ps.setString(5,dates);

                            // call executeUpdate to execute our sql update statement
                            ps.executeUpdate();

                            if (ps.executeUpdate()==1) {

                                String queryBRTR= ("Update BRTR set end_break = ?, status= ? where  and PF_No= ? and work_date= ?");
                                PreparedStatement br = con.prepareStatement(queryBRTR);
                                // set the preparedstatement parameters
                                br.setString(1,currentTime);
                                br.setString(2,a_status);
//                                br.setString(3,b_status);
                                br.setString(3,OperatorPF);
                                br.setString(4,dates);
                                // call executeUpdate to execute our sql update statement

                                br.executeUpdate();


                                if( br.executeUpdate()==1){

                                    z="You may resume your work now";
                                }
                                else{
                                    ps.close();
                                    br.close();
                                }
```

Please highlight if there is any mistake or suggest another way that would work to update both table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
int rowsChanged = ps.executeUpdate();

if (rowsChanged  >= 1) {
```

You were calling `executeUpdate` twice.

- Should not re-execute the PreparedStatement
- Status has changed so even if you could re-use PreparedStatement , the update would probably fail

Comment: thanks for responding. But the results are still the same. It only run the first update query and failed to the next query.

Comment: Did you also change `br.executeUpdate();


                                if( br.executeUpdate()==1){
` ?

Comment: yes sir. Btw, I've found the problem which is caused by my data in the second table. Thank you for your help sir. The codes work well now.